# Why does 'include' not include a defined constant in a separate file?

Tags: php, variables, xampp, include, constants

i have a problem with included file in php.

I have 2 file "settings.php" and "test.php" (hosted in localhost with all xampp's default settings and "allow_url_include=1").

Now. This is the content of file "settings.php":

```
<?
   define("TEST_INFO","Lorem ipsum");
?>
```

And this is the file that include "setting.php":

"test.php":

```
<?
include("http://127.0.0.1/projectFolder/settings.php");

echo(TEST_INFO);
?>
```

The result of "test.php" is:

> Notice: Use of undefined constant TEST_INFO - assumed 'TEST_INFO' in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\projectFolder\test.php on line 4 TEST_INFO

The "include" function not make any error or warning as if it were performed correctly, but the constant (or any variable) defined in the included file not work.

If i try to include file "setting.php" without all url, it work correctly. `include("settings.php");`

But i need that it work so as: `include("http://127.0.0.1/projectFolder/settings.php");`

Thanks.

Comment: turning the `allow_url_include` option is risky. You really need tutorials on security for php apps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are including a resource from a URL.

1. The PHP in the first script makes an HTTP request to the URL
2. The PHP that runs the `define` (in the second script) is executed on the server
3. The output is sent over HTTP to the `include()`
4. The output is included in the first page

The `define` statement is executed in a completely different script (possibly on a different server!).

If you want to execute PHP in the context of the current script, then you **must** `include` a *local file* and not an *HTTP URL*.

Comment: Though not an issue, might be worth mentioning issues that can be caused with short tags.